# transformation, CRTM05 Projection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3

I have a network dataset with GCS_WGS_1984 coordinate system

and a layer of districts of Costa Rica country with Unkonown Spatial Reference

TOOLS ta use "defined Projection" Input is where districts and coordinate system is GCS_WGS_1984

but the layers do not match

just as it was with a CRTM05 prj. to download

but does not match

I asked to make a transformation but do not know how

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the dataset has no prj (or has an incorrect prj), what I typically do in this situation is to come up with a list of the most likely projections for the area in question. This website can help you identify those.

http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/
You can search for Costa Rica and then click the link to view all.

Then you can rename the incorrect prj (if present) so that arcmap will ingnore it. So now you have a layer with no projection information and your layer that is WGS1984 (geographic).

Next you will want to set the projection of the dataframe to the first (most likely) projection from the list that you came up with and work from that in succession (one at a time) until you find the one that makes the data layers match up.